# How to programatically access JCR 283 compliant CRX repository?

Tags: java, jcr, sling, livecycle, crx

I am working with Adobe LiveCycle ES4 which uses a CRX repository. I wanted to write a Java program that could access the content of the JCR 283 compliant CRX repository. The application runs on WebSphere server.

Many websites mention JCR-1.0 API to connect to a JCR repository, but it doesn't contain any class to make a connection to server.

I believe Adobe LiveCycle uses a OSGi framework. Should I make use of OSGi services?

If yes, please suggest method for that or should I use Apache Sling services to connect to the CRX repository?

I am not fully aware of technology stack of LiveCycle ES4 application. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: When I google for `jcr crx tutorial`, first few results pint me to https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/crx/2-3/developing/accessing_the_crx.html or http://aem-docs.tostring.me/?d=/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/platform/access-jcr.html - did you read any of these?

Answer (score 0):

With LiveCycle ES4, and AEM Forms JEE (Java Enterprise Edition) you essentially have 2 platforms architectures to choose from when developing. OSGI (Open Service Gateway Initiative) functionality comes from the Sling Launchpad portion of the platform. Every URL available under the **/lc** context URL comes from the OSGI portion of the platform, the rest is JEE/LiveCycle.

To access the JCR (Java Content Repository) you can:

- Create a LiveCycle process that will communicate with the JCR over HTTP/HTTPS
- Create a Java application that uses the LiveCycle APIs to communicate with the JCR over HTTP/HTTPS once again
- Create an OSGI service or JSP deployed the the Sling Launchpad that will communicate with the JCR using the direct JCR APIs
- Communicate with the JCR directly using it's RESTful interface.

Here's another post that provide an Adobe article on accessing the JCR: [storing custom data in AEM 6.1 JCR repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35165322/storing-custom-data-in-aem-6-1-jcr-repository)